# How will I get both textbox value in my method argument?

Tags: razor

```
<body >
<a href="#" class="close"></a>

@using (Html.BeginForm("sendcode", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div id="popup">
<div class="selected">You Selected:</div>
<div class="sname">@ViewBag.selectsong</div>
<input name="sSongName" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.selectsong"/>
<div class="enter" style="width:458px;height:37px; text-align:left;">
<div class="selected">Enter your mobile number</div>

<div class="mobileno">
<div><div class="spann">+91</div><input name="MNumber" type="text" class="mobileinput"/></div>
</div>
<div class="confirm">
<input name="" type="button" class="confirmb" value="Confirm" onclick="@Url.Action("sendcode", "Home", new { })"/>
</div>
<div class="applicablee">* charges applicable</div>
</div>

</div>
}
</body>
```

Below is my method which has been written in Home controller and I want to retrieve both textvalue in method as argument ?

```
 public string sendcode(string MNumber, string SongName)
        {
return (MNumber+" "+SongName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match your parameter names with the name attribute of the input fields.

```
<input name="sSongName" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.selectsong"/>
<input name="MNumber" type="text" class="mobileinput"/>


public string sendcode(string sSongName, string MNumber)
{
     //Do Something
}
```